# Load events into calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a XML-file, which contains the data of a calendar. I want to load the events dynamically into a calendar using AJAX. I want to get the XML-elements called "afspraak" (four of them). The XML-file can be viewed here: http://dimitrisnijder.nl/files/agenda.xml

I'm trying to do that using the following code:

```
function agendaLoad(){

    $(".title").html(monthLabels[thisMonth]+" "+thisYear);


    $.get(
        "agendaSaver.php",
        {month: thisMonth,
        year: thisYear},
        processXML,
        "xml"
    );
}

function processXML(xml) {      
$("agenda afspraak", xml).each(function() {     

    var dag = $(this).find("dag").text(); 
    var maand = $(this).find("maand").text();       
    var jaar = $(this).find("jaar").text();
    var onderwerp = $(this).find("onderwerp").text();
    var tijd = $(this).find("tijd").text();
    var beschrijving = $(this).find("beschrijving").text();

    if((maand == today.getMonth()+1) && (jaar == today.getFullYear())) {

        $("#day"+dag).append('<div class="afspraak">'+onderwerp+'</div> <p class="beschrijving"><strong>'+tijd+' '+onderwerp+'</strong><br/>'+beschrijving+'</p>');
    }
});
}
```

This partially works. The script will load the fourth event ("afspraak") into the agenda, and displays it on the 25th of March 2012. But that event is loaded on the 25th day of every month. The first three events arent loaded at all..

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your processXML() function seems to be fine at first glance.  So, could it be that the xml returned by agendaSaver.php only includes the fourth event?  Test for this by putting *alert(xml)* in the first line of processXML().

Comment: I've tested agendaSaver.php already. If I run it in my browser, the whole XML-document is displayed, which is the same as http://dimitrisnijder.nl/files/agenda.xml

Comment: So you are sure that if you pass, for instance, month 01 (januari) to agendaSaver.php, that the two events for 'januari' are returned?  Have you placed an alert before and after the conditional test inside processXML, like this: alert('Maand: ' + maand) to make sure the condition fires?

Comment: maand is equal to 'januari' instead of to 0 (in processXML). You must use some kind of array indexOf() method to return the month given it's name, from your monthLabels array, I think.

Comment: Check your XML file: You use 03 for March, but month names for other months.  If you replace all the month names with their integer index, your code should work better.

Comment: When I put "document.write(maand);" in the if-statement, 03 is returned. So the function gets the number of the month from the XML-file. Maybe it's because the zero is in front of the three?

Comment: Yes, your XML returns a string for `maand`, I suggest you use `parseInt(maand)` instead of just `maand` in your if condition.  Also, there are mistakes in your XML file:  You must replace the names of the other months with their integer representations.

Comment: I replaced maand with parseInt(maand) in the if-statement, but that didn't solve the problem.. All the months are represented bij numbers in the XML file? The first event takes place in month nr. 1, just like the second event. The third event takes place in month nr. 2. The XML-file in the first post wasn't the right one, sorry. In the XML-file used by the code above, january is represented as 01, february as 02 and march as 03.

Comment: By the way: I've returned maand and today.getMonth()+1 in the "afspraak" div in the if-statement, but in every month is the same value returned: 03 for maand and 3 for today.getMonth()+1..

Comment: And parseInt(maand) and today.getMonth()+1 returns 3 and  in every month

Comment: But `todaygetMonth()+1` will always return `3` while we are in March (which is at the moment).  Which is why the condition is only be true for the 03 entry in the XML file, and not the others...?  Change today.getMonth()+1 to `2` or `1` to test what happens if we are in February or January.  Also, did you check what happens to the XML which is returned when the `month` key in the get data array is not equal to 3?

Comment: It's fixed. I used the variable thisMonth (which contains  today.getMonth()) instead of today.getMonth(). That variable is updated, each time the month is switched. So if you go back to february, the variable will return 2 instead of three (March). Thanks for your help!